# issue with cloning private git repo with chef-solo

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, chef-solo, knife-solo

I am trying to use chef-solo to pull private git repo. I used following steps to create my setup.

1. Create necessary data bags to encrypt private ssh keys

a. create encrypted key file

> EDITOR=vim knife solo data bag create secret 
>   --secret_file=...

b. remove newline and copy to clipboard

> Select cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa | tr -d '\r\n' > pbcopy

c. Edit the file with

```
>    { 
>      “id”: “<app_name>”,
>      “private_key”: <Private key copied from clipboard>    
     }
```

d. It correctly creates data bag and I can view it

```
 - knife solo data bag show secrets <app_name>    
 - knife solo data bag show secrets <app_name> --secret-file  ~/.chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret
```

2. ssh-wrapper to refer to the private key file

   > #!/bin/sh    exec ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o
   >   StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i  "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa" "$@"
3. Using git resource, checkout or clone the repo

   > ```
   > git "#{node[:test][:base]}/test" do
   >     repository "git@github.test/test.git"
   >     reference "master"
   >     action :sync
   >     destination node[:test][:base]
   >     user "#{node[:test][:user]}"
   >     group "#{node[:test][:user]}"
   >     ssh_wrapper "#{node[:test][:base]}/.ssh/git-ssh-wrapper.sh"
   > end
   > ```

The attributes.rb file contains following

```
default[:test][:base]  = "/home/ubuntu"  
default[:test][:log_dir] = "/var/log/test"  
default[:test][:loglevel]   = "info" 
default[:test][:user]       = "ubuntu"  
default[:test][:virtualenv] ="/home/ubuntu/environments/test"  
default[:test][:deploy_repo] = "git@github.com:test/test.git"  
default[:test][:deploy_branch] = "master"  
default[:test][:deploy_dir] = "/srv/test"
```

In the end, when I run following command 
'knife solo bootstrap ubuntu@' I observe following.

- The code gets stuck, while running "sync" action and never completes
  it.
- On the AWS instance, the private key id_rsa is being generated in
  .ssh directory, however when performing ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa it asks
  for passphrase (even if the original ssh-keygen  command did not have
  any password)
- On the AWS instance, performing manual git ls remote
  git@github.com:test fails while it's successful on local machine The
  authentication daemon is not running by default, so how to start it
  automatically?

Again, all of the above can be due to the fact that private key. However, while comparing the decrypted private key content on remote machine matches the local private key (original key without encryption).

It would be great, to get some insight into the above behavior and potential solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you writing the encrypted data bag's contents to ~/.ssh/id_rsa? And does it appear to be the same after you've copied it?

Comment: I am writing it in following manner.                                                          ```secrets = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load( "secrets", "<app_name>" )
file "#{node[:<app_name>][:base]}/.ssh/id_rsa" do
  content secrets["id_rsa"]
  owner node[:<app_name>][:user]
  group node[:<app_name>][:user]
  mode 0600
end                                                                                                                         `The content is same except the id_rsa file does not have new lines.

Comment: That sounds fine, then. I might try adding back the newlines to check, but I don't think that's the problem.